# Issue with Email Action on object and related to Pre-defined fields

Tags: email, email2case, send-email, service, email2salesforce

I have a 2 email action on the case object and for both of them I have  "To Address" pre-defined but sending an email from the 1 email action then it is populating the correct "To address" which is defined for 1 email action but when sending 2nd email from the 2nd Action at that time the "To Address" is populated as 1st Action pre-defined values only it should have populated 2nd Actions Pre-defined values.

How we can fix or any workaround to achieve above mention requirement?

Answer (score 0):

> Please check that different mail ids were mentioned on those two actions.

Below is my workaround of the issue in my org.

[image]

[image]

Below images are the results of first and second mail actions.

**1. First Mail Action**
[image]

**2. Second Mail Action**
[image]

I hope it resolves your issue!